# C: Reading 128 bit value from flash address

Tags: c

I want to read a specific 128 bit value in memory that equals the following:

```
128 bit val = 0171EC07F2E6C383FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

This id is visible when flashing a binary

```
Read Intel HEX application image with 608 bytes.
  Received autobaud response:
    Product ID: xxxxxx      
    Revision: xxx
    Serial number: 0171EC07F2E6C383FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
    User code present.
    User code checksum failed.
    Write protection disabled.
    Read protection disabled.
  Download completed.
  Run command sent.
Programming flash image.
  Read Intel HEX flash image with 189248 bytes.
  Autobaud succeeded.
  Flash completed.
```

This is the code I am using to read that address

```
uint8_t *address = (uint8_t *)0x34576;
uint8_t reg[16] = {0};
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    reg[i] = *address;
    printf("reg[%d]= 0x%x\r\n", i, reg[i]);
    *address++;
}
```

This is the output I'm getting:

```
reg[0]= 0x10
reg[1]= 0x17
reg[2]= 0xce
reg[3]= 0x70
reg[4]= 0x2f
reg[5]= 0x6e
reg[6]= 0x3c
reg[7]= 0x38
reg[8]= 0xff
reg[9]= 0xff
reg[10]= 0xff
reg[11]= 0xff
reg[12]= 0xff
reg[13]= 0xff
reg[14]= 0xff
reg[15]= 0xff
```

As can be seen from the output the byte order is mixed up. Is this because of little/big endian. How do I convert the value to be equal to `128 bit val`

Comment: You are correct; it is because of [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). You can either swap the bytes (0<->3 and 1<->2), or you can read the input one byte at a time.

Comment: There is something else wrong - the nibbles in each byte are also the wrong way up:(

Comment: `0x34576` doesn't seem to align to 4 byte boundary. That will be a problem on some architectures. Maybe it would be better to construct your array one *byte* at the time.

Comment: How are you writing that 128-bit value to memory? I just tested your code and it read the bytes correctly nibble-wise (besides the Little Endian issue)

Comment: @Aziz I don't write it there, it's stored there by the bootloader.

Comment: what machine, compiler, debugger are you using?

Comment: @aziz machine is an arm mcu

Comment: As @user694733 suggested, reading from an unaligned address could cause issues like the one you're seeing. It's best to read one byte at a time.

Comment: @aziz Question edited to be one byte at a time, but still the nibbles in each byte are the wrong way

Comment: The data residing in  `(uint8_t *)0x34576` is not 0171EC07F2E6C383FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.  Unposted code needs review.  Post the evidence that the expected data is 0171EC0....  This is a little/big endian _nibble_ issue.

Comment: @chux question updated with evidence

Comment: "Serial number" is not an `uint128_t`, but uses a different layout.  Simple reverse nibbles on reading.  Think of it more as a packed array of hex characters.  IMO, this looks like a weakness in the tool reporting the Serial number.

Comment: @chux how would I reverse the nibbles?

Comment: @KevinMoloney `byte = (byte >> 4) | (byte << 4)`

Comment: BTW: What program are you using that reports, "Read Intel HEX application.    ...."?

Comment: @chux I wondered about that too.  If the executable code is also getting loaded with the nibbles swapped then.....

Comment: @MartinJames As `uint128_t` is not a required type and this code and the report program are effectively re-inventing 128-bit integer solutions, it is easy to see that "inconsistencies" occur.  Time for `uint128_t/uint256_t` in C.